# Lambda: Declare Generic Type Inline

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

**My Goal**

I want to write a generic timing function (I removed the actual timing code for this question as it doesn't really matter).

I have a function with unknown input and output. I want to run this function a couple of times in a loop and pass it the loop variable.

To do this, I defined an interface that can transform the loop variable to the type that the function needs.

**My Code**

```
interface Function<R,T> {
    R run(T input);
}

interface InputGenerater<T> {
    T fromLoop(int i);
}

public static void time(Function func, InputGenerater in) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        func.run(in.fromLoop(i));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example: my function expects a string, so we transform the loop variable to a string:
    InputGenerater<String> intToString = (int i) -> String.valueOf(i) + "test";

    Function<String, String> funcToTest = (String s) -> s + s;
    time(funcToTest, intToString);

    Function<String, String> funcToTest2 = (String s) -> s + s + s;
    time(funcToTest2, intToString);

    // I can not only test string->string functions, but anything I want:
    InputGenerater<Integer> intToInt = (int i) -> i;
    Function<Integer, Integer> funcToTestInt = (Integer i) -> i + i;
    time(funcToTestInt, intToInt);
}
```

**My Problem**

The above code works fine, but I would prefer not to have the `funcToTest`, etc variables as they are only used on one line.

So I would like the main method to look like this:

```
    InputGenerater<String> intToString = (int i) -> String.valueOf(i) + "test";

    time((String s) -> s + s, intToString);
    time((String s) -> s + s + s, intToString);

    InputGenerater<Integer> intToInt = (int i) -> i;
    time((Integer i) -> i + i, intToInt);
```

But it doesn't work: `Incompatible types in lambda expression`.

Is there a way to declare the parameter type inline, instead of declaring it by declaring the `Function<String, String>` variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using raw types in your time function: you should use generics and your code will compile as expected:

```
public static <R, T> void time(Function<R, T> func, InputGenerater<T> in)
```

Also note that the `Function` interface that you have defined [already exists in the JDK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) (its method is `apply` instead of `run`) and the `InputGenerator` also exists and [is called `IntFunction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntFunction.html).

So it would make sense to get rid of those interfaces and use those provided by the JDK instead.

So the final version could look like:

```
public static <R, T> void time(Function<R, T> func, IntFunction<T> in) { ... }
```

and you main method:

```
time(s -> s + s, i -> i + "test"); //s is a string
time(i -> i + i, i -> i); //i is an int
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about those interfaces, I will use them. But if I use `String` in the function signature as you suggest, I could only ever test a function that goes from `String` to `String`. The whole point of generics and the input generator was that I also want to test functions which for example accept integers. You are right that I probably shouldn't just omit them, but `<R,T> void time(Function<R,T> func, InputGenerater<T> in` doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @tim If you make that change, the code at the bottom of your question should compile fine.

Comment: true, but `time((Integer i) -> i + i, intToInt);` wouldn't work. I updated my question to make it clearer.

Comment: @tim `time((Integer i) -> i + i, (int i) -> i);` compiles fine. Actually `time(i -> i + i, i -> i);` compiles too.

Comment: now it works great (with the generic function signature), I must have messed up somewhere. Thanks!